# the query does not give the results I want

Tags: php, sql, database

I have created this **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a2d72/4)** demo for better understand the problem.

First, I will try to tell you what I want to do. People can create their own group pages via facebook. I made it possible for people to set up their own group pages in my own social networking project. We know that facebook is showing on the main page under the name of recommended groups. There are two or more different suggested group. That's exactly what I want to do. I want to show suggested group from my main page.

As you can see in the query there are some conditions available, These are respectively as follows:

1-) The person who set up the group will not see the group he has set up in the recommended groups.

2-) The person can not see joined group from the recommended groups.

In the recommended groups, I would like to show only two suggested groups.

The query is here:

```
SELECT
    G.group_id, 
    G.group_owner_id, 
    G.group_name, 
    G.group_title, 
    G.group_cover, 
    F.group_oid, 
    F.group_user_id 
FROM group_users F
INNER JOIN groups G
    ON G.group_id = F.group_oid
WHERE
    G.status = '1' AND
    F.group_oid <> '10' AND
    F.group_user_id <> '10' 
GROUP BY
    F.group_oid 
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 2
```

1. First Problem is: People see his own group from suggested groups. I
   don't want to show his own group from suggested in this query.
2. Second problem is: People see his joined group from suggested
   groups. I don't want to show his joined group from suggested in this
   query.

You can test first problem with the demo as follows:

The number 10 is who created group sapsik (**group_id 16**). The query must be disable this row in output because we use 10 in this query.

```
F.group_oid <> '10' AND
F.group_user_id <> '10'
```

And also you can test Second problem with the demo as follows:

The numver 8 is not created his own group, number 8 just joined group 16 (`table group_users, row group_oid 16 , group_user_id 8`). But if you change the following line like this

```
F.group_oid <> '8' AND
F.group_user_id <> '8'
```

number 8 continues to see the group that is still registered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need to fetch `F.group_oid` and `F.group_user_id`?

If not, you could use this query:

```
SELECT
    G.group_id, 
    G.group_owner_id, 
    G.group_name, 
    G.group_title, 
    G.group_cover
FROM groups G
WHERE
    G.status = '1' AND
    G.group_id NOT IN (
      SELECT F.group_oid
      FROM group_users F
      WHERE F.group_oid = '10' OR
      F.group_user_id = '10'
    )
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 2
```

The problem with your query is that if two users are in the same group, `F.group_user_id <> '10'` will always be true.

Answer (score 2):

Another version using post-aggregate filtering.To remember: WHERE filters rows HAVING filters groups.

```
SELECT
    G.group_id, 
    G.group_owner_id, 
    G.group_name, 
    G.group_title, 
    G.group_cover, 
    F.group_oid, 
    F.group_user_id 
FROM group_users F
INNER JOIN groups G
    ON G.group_id = F.group_oid
    WHERE G.status = '1'
GROUP BY
    F.group_oid 
    HAVING SUM(F.group_oid = 10)=0
    AND SUM(F.group_user_id = 10)=0
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 2
```